align top on a minipage next to an image
I'm trying to put a picture on the left and text on the right, but I can't find a way to have the text align with the top of the image (without using \vskip-50pt
here is my code :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Insertion d'image
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\hspace*{-27pt}
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
    \hspace*{-14pt}
        {\includegraphics[width = 1.164\textwidth]{test}}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{28pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}%
    %\vskip -50pt
    texte test
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

here is what it looks like :

and here is what I would like it to look like:


You could use the valign=... option from the adjustbox package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Insertion d'image
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width =\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}%
texte test
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}



Thanks, it does work fine, however, I simplyed my code a bit to much, I use a special command to show the figure and now it doesn't work, I updating the code in my question

@edwylin If you have a new question, you should ask a new question.

here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/728252/341431
