align top on a minipage next to an image with annotation
I'm trying to put a picture on the left and text on the right, but I can't find a way to have the text align with the top of the image (without using \vskip-95pt)
here is my code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xparse} % for \NewDocumentCommand
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\annotatedFigureBox{bottom left point}{top righ corner}{label}{label coordinate}[main color][backgroud color]
\NewDocumentCommand{\annotatedFigureBoxCustom}{m m m m O{black} O{white}}{
    \draw[#5,thick,rounded corners] (#1) rectangle (#2);
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
        % empty
    \else
        \annotatedFigureLetter{#3}{#4}[#5][#6]
    \fi
}

%\annotatedFigureBox{xA}{yA}{width}{height}{label}{label pos}[main color][backgroud color]
\NewDocumentCommand{\annotatedFigureBox}{m m m m m m O{black} O{white}}{
    \FPeval{\xB}{#1 + #3}   % xB yB : top right corner
    \FPeval{\yB}{#2 + #4}
    \FPeval{\xC}{#1 + #3/2} % xC yC : midle point
    \FPeval{\yC}{#2 + #4/2}
    \ifnum#6=1 % getting label coordinate with the coordinate pos #6
        \def\a{#1}
        \def\b{#2}
    \else\ifnum#6=2
        \def\a{\xB}
        \def\b{#2}
    \else\ifnum#6=3
        \def\a{\xB}
        \def\b{\yB}
    \else\ifnum#6=4
        \def\a{#1}
        \def\b{\yB}
    \else\ifnum#6=5
        \def\a{\xC}
        \def\b{#2}
    \else\ifnum#6=6
        \def\a{\xB}
        \def\b{\yC}
    \else\ifnum#6=7
        \def\a{\xC}
        \def\b{\yB}
    \else\ifnum#6=8
        \def\a{#1}
        \def\b{\yC}
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \annotatedFigureBoxCustom{#1,#2}{\xB,\yB}{#5}{\a,\b}[#7][#8]
}

%\annotatedFigureLetterCustom{label}{x, y}[main color][backgroud color]
\NewDocumentCommand{\annotatedFigureLetter}{m m O{black} O{white}}{
    \node at (#2) [fill=#4,thick,shape=circle,draw=#3,inner sep=1pt,font=\sffamily,text=#3] {\small\textbf{#1}};
}

\newcommand*\annotatedFigureText[4]{\node[draw=none, anchor=south west, text=#2, inner sep=0, text width=#3\linewidth,font=\sffamily] at (#1){#4};}

\newenvironment {annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { #1};\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}{\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\hspace*{-27pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \hspace*{-14pt}
    \begin{annotatedFigure}
        {\includegraphics[width = 1.164\textwidth,valign=t]{test}}
        \annotatedFigureBox{0.01}{0.649}{0.145}{0.11}{A}{2}[red]
    \end{annotatedFigure}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{28pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}%
    % \vskip-95pt
    texte test
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

here is what it looks like :

here is what I would like it to look like :


Your baseline is being set by tikzpicture, regardless of valign or [t].
\newenvironment {annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(top)]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { #1};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}% BODY here
{\end{scope}
\path (current bounding box.north) ++(0pt,-\ht\strutbox) coordinate (top);
\end{tikzpicture}}


I don't understand what it does but works

First, vertical alignment is based on baselines.  You can show the baseline by adding \hfill\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}} to the end of a line.  By default, the baseline for a tikzpicture is at the bottom, but you can change it using the [baseline=...] keyword.  \ht\strutbox is the distance from the top to the baseline for a normal line of text.  Note that the [t] and [b] options for minipage use the first or last baseline, but since you only have one baseline, it makes no difference.

One can alsu use \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{...}.
